# type conversion warnings in porting 32 bit app to 64 bit app using sizeof operator

Tags: c, 64-bit, gsoap, ansi-c

I am porting an application from 32 bit to 64 bit.  The application includes gSoap generated ANSI C source code.  The prototypes of several generated soap functions include `int` data types in the argument list, such as:

```
int PASCAL FAR setsockopt (
                       __in SOCKET s,
                       __in int level,
                       __in int optname,
                       __in_bcount_opt(optlen) const char FAR * optval,
                       __in int optlen);
```

But, when called in stdsoap2.c, the 5th argument in this example is passed the `sizeof` macro:

```
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char*)&linger, sizeof(struct linger)))
{ ...
}
```

The `sizeof` macro returns a value of the `size_t` type which is just an `unsigned int`.  When compiling in the 32 bit environment, this presented no problem, however, when compiling in the 64 bit environment, the warning:   *"Conversion from* `unsigned __int64` *to* `int` *might lose data"*.

I understand the data loss problem.  My question is where and how should it be placed in the code to address the problem short of `(int)` type casting for each `sizeof` macro being passed as an `int` within `stdsoap2.c` (there are 32 warnings in `stdsoap.c` alone).  I would like to avoid editing an automatically generated source file if possible.

For those familiar with `gsoap` methods, I have included the following:

```
#ifdef WITH_SOAPDEFS_H
# include "soapdefs.h"      /* include user-defined stuff */
#endif
```

and am using `soapdefs.h` in my project.  This file has project wide scope, perhaps this file would be a good place for addressing the problem, then the question would just be *how*?

Comment: What version of Gsoap do you use?

Comment: If you can't change the prototype **AND** the function itself, I would just ignore the warning and complain to the gSoap authors about their wrong choice of types.

Comment: Note that ignoring the warning is not so bad. You are guaranteed a proper conversion from `size_t` to `int` as long as you have the prototype in scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size_t` isn't "just an `unsigned int`"; as the warning shows, on a 64-bit platform it's commonly larger than that.

Where you should do the check depends on the application, but if you're passing the value of a `sizeof` expression, you could replace that with an appropriately defined constant:

```
enum {
    SIZEOF_LINGER = sizeof(struct linger);
};
```

The compiler will issue a warning if the constant is too large to be converted, so if you compile with (the equivalent of GCC's) `-Wall -Werror`, you're safe.

Comment: You don't need the cast ... let the compiler do it automatically

Comment: Instead of a const-qualified variable you could use an enumeration. `enum { SIZEOF_LINGER = ... };` This would have the advantage that it counts as constant integer expression and you wouldn't have a copy of that variable in every compilation unit.

Comment: @larsmans (and @Jens) I am a little late, but thanks.  Your comments got it done.

Answer (score 1):

in cases where I cannot change the method taking an int to take a size_t instead, I usually resolve to boost::numeric_cast in C++ or similar in C, this seems the best thing to do and effectively gets rid of the warning while still remaining safe.

The basic idea is:

```
int safe_cast( size_t n )
{
  if( n > INT_MAX )
  {
     //do something to handle this error
  }
  return (int) n;
}
```

In your case however you can be pretty sure that `sizeof( struct linger )` won't exceed INT_MAX so you might as well provide a global constant that is an int and holds that size.

Comment: This is a good solution in case of, say, `strlen`, but it won't catch the error at compile-time for a `sizeof`.